# Flutter returning (String?) => String?

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, dart, mobile

Can somebody help me. I'm trying to get string value that is being return as (String?) => String?

```
FXForm.email(
  context,
  labelText: "Email Address",
  controller: notifier.emailAddressController,
  onChanged: (FormFieldValidator<String> item) => print(item),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

`FormFieldValidator` is a `typedef` that defines the signature for validating a form field:

```
String? FormFieldValidator<T>(T? value)
```

Your code is defining that `item` is of this type, i.e. a function, and then you are trying to print it.

I guess that your `onChanged` property requires a `FormFieldValidator`. If this is the case you should have:

```
onChanged: (String? item) { 
    print(item);
    return null;    // Return an error string to display if invalid, or null otherwise.
}
```

This defines a function that accepts an optional String, which matches `FormFieldValidator`.